# Not found: type SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor when trying to run SparkSessionExtensionsTest

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, antlr4

I want to learn the spark session extension mechanism and I'm trying to run the spark example.
I'm trying to run `SparkSessionExtensionTest` in Spark project, and I'm getting the following error:

```
"not found: type SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor
class AstBuilder extends SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor[AnyRef] with SQLConfHelper with Logging {"
```

I'm guessing it's related to ANTLR4 dependencies, but they are descripbed in the pom file and I also downloaded ANTLR4 to IntelliJ. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about compiling (parts of) [Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark), then you don't need to download anything related to ANTLR yourself.

The fact that you're getting a compile time error stating `SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor` could not be found, suggests that you did not invoke the correct maven phase that triggers ANTLR to generate this file. Try running `mvn compile` in the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

YOu're right, its not related to ANTLR. the problem was resolved after cleaning up the cache, making sure using the right JAVA and SCALA version and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).